# Kivy - How does one get the correct character from a keypress with/without modifiers?

Tags: python, kivy

Using Kivy with Python, how does one get the correct character from a keypress with/without modifiers?

I do not want to use a kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.  I just want to know what character the user is trying to enter.

I can use the keyboard returned from [kivy.core.window.Window.request_keyboard()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=request_keyboard#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.request_keyboard) to get the scancode of the currently pressed key, but this does not account for modifiers, i.e. the shift key.

Obviously I can write something myself that checks if shift is pressed at the same time, and if so convert it to the corresponding character.  But this solution isn't portable unless everyone's keyboard has the same layout as mine.

Is there some way to get the correct character according to the system keymap?

I took a quick look at the [TextInput source](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/textinput.py) but I can't see any calls to request_keyboard().

Do not tell me to use a TextInput.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/keyboardlistener.py). It gives you the modifiers by name (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Crtl</kbd>, etc)

If you want your widget to listen to all the inputs no matter another widget has focus just change this:

```
def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None
```

to:

```
def _keyboard_closed(self):
        pass
```

that will avoid the widget releasing the keyboard, so it will listen everything all the time.

And

The TextInput makes the call to `request_keyboard()` in the `_ensure_keyboard()` method of FocusBehaviour called every time the focus changes to true:

```
def _on_focus(self, instance, value, *largs):
        if self.keyboard_mode == 'auto':
            if value:
                self._bind_keyboard()
        ....

def _bind_keyboard(self):
        self._ensure_keyboard()
        ....

def _ensure_keyboard(self):
        if self._keyboard is None:
            self._requested_keyboard = True
            keyboard = self._keyboard =\
                EventLoop.window.request_keyboard(
                    self._keyboard_released, self, input_type=self.input_type)
        ....
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I can see the call to request_keyboard, thanks for pointing that out.  The reason I wanted to find that was so that I could see how it's handling keypresses (i.e. in _on_keyboard_down) so that I could see how it returns the character that was input.

Unfortunately FocusBehaviour doesn't seem to be the place where keypresses are processed.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Haven't you tried the code in the link?. I tried it and it gave me the key, keycode and the modifiers. If you want the actual character (i.e user press "a" and "shift" so the character is "A") you can bind to the keyboard on_textinput() method. If you really, really want the scancode I think your only option is to edit the _on_window_key_down() in the Keyboard source code to also pass the scancode to on_key_down()(Awful, but works). Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, how to handle modified characters. I know it is not the proper solution, but it is works. If you know the proper way, please post it below...

code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window, Keyboard
from kivy.logger import Logger

class textInsert(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(textInsert, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.super = []

        text = StringProperty()

        ########################################
        keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_released, self)
        keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._keyboard_on_key_down, on_key_up=self._keyboard_released)

        ########################################
    #end def __init__

    def _keyboard_released(self, window, keycode):
        self.super = []

    def _keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, super):
        if 'lctrl' in self.super and keycode[1] == 's':
            Logger.info("Item saved, {}".format(self.super))
            self.super = []
            return False
        elif 'lctrl' not in self.super and keycode[1] in ["lctrl"]:
            self.super.append(keycode[1])
            return False
        else:
            Logger.info("key {} pressed.".format(keycode))
            return False


class ROOT(App):
   def build(self):
      return textInsert()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ROOT().run()
```